# some users get error "List does not exist" and others don't but they all belong to the same group

Tags: list, permissions

We have a subsite that shows data of a list that belongs to the main site and some users are getting the error "List does not exist" but others don't, they belong to a SharePoint group and we set the permissions of the list to Read but it still happens and we don't know what else to try.

advices?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is it 2007 or 2010 version?

May be the List may not be inheriting permission from the site(?)

If SP 2010, Navigate to List's permission page anc you will see an option named "Check Permission" and you can use this to check individual user's permission for the list.

If MOSS 2007, you can use [Acess Checker WebPart](http://accesschecker.codeplex.com/) to find the individual user's permission for this list. Hope this will give you some ideas to debug the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's 2007, is there another way to check about the unique permissions?, we don't have direct access to the server, we would need to ask the administrator to use the Access Checker Webpart and they would take time to approve it...

Comment: Go to the list, select Settings, List Settings and click on Permissions for this list.  If you see a bunch of names with check boxes beside it, that means it's using custom permissions and they can be reset via Actions, Inherit permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it might be using custom permissions.  Go to the list, select Settings, List Settings and click on Permissions for this list. If you see a bunch of names with check boxes beside it, that means it's using custom permissions and they can be reset via Actions, Inherit permissions.